# How can I split this counter and export it to .csv?

Tags: python, csv

I'm working on this Python(2.7) code, analyzing a .txt file for the 50 most common words. The next step is exporting the words and their number of occurrences to a .csv file. I am exporting to the .csv file, but the code keeps grouping the words and their numbers with punctuations and parentheses. I need it in two columns, with each group on a new row.

For example: ('the', 329) needs to appear as two different columns, the | 329

I think I can pull it off using regex, but I really don't know how. Any help is  appreciated.

```
import re
import collections
import csv
from collections import Counter

words = re.findall('\w+', open('document.txt').read().lower())
thing = Counter(words).most_common(50)

PDFiles = "PDFiles.csv"
with open(PDFiles, "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    for val in thing:
            writer.writerow(val) # edited
```

With the latest edit, the text appears as

```
tell     | 329
        0| 65
```

Comment: Can you share us what you are getting in think variable as a sample.

Comment: Try `writer.writerow(val)`.

Comment: writer.writerow(val) works 90%! Oddly, in the first column, while the words are by default indented left, if a most common occurrence is a number, it is indented on the right side of the first column.

Comment: Is that padding in the file, or is that opening it in Excel and having Excel auto-convert it to a number and right-align it?

Comment: There are numbers in the file, although it may be an Excel issue with how LibreOffice imports the csv formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

writer.writerow([val[0],val[1]])

Comment: It didn't effect the indenting.

Comment: Indenting is due to field format in excel, it has nothing to do with coding, What you can do is: right click on column header than click on format cells, and then select text from category.

Comment: Thank you, I'll just have to deal with the formatting and play with it in Excel.

Comment: Actually, how would I just remove the numbers from the search query?

Comment: `for val in thing:
      if not val[0].isdigit():
         writer.writerow([val[0],val[1]])`